No module named 'awscli_plugin_execute_api'
I'm trying to use aws cli in Mac M3 but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.
➜  ~ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
➜  ~ aws --version

No module named 'awscli_plugin_execute_api'

